# A food's Rabbanut kashrus claim is in plain text. There's no kosher symbol, logo, or emblem. Can you trust the kashrus claim?

Tags: halacha, kashrut-kosher, eretz-yisrael, hechsher-certification, state-of-israel

## Background

You're considering buying a package of kasha, or roasted buckwheat.  It was made in China.

(I once asked a rabbi at COR, the Kashruth Council of Canada.  He told me that, if you buy roasted buckwheat from such a place:  It's preferable not to buy it unless it has kosher certification.  You don't know what other foods were roasted on the same production line.)

You can see a photo of the package below.

The package does not have any hechsher, or kosher certification logo, anywhere on the front or back.  It has the English words "Kosher Parve", but these words alone do not prove that something is kosher.  It also has the Hebrew words:

נבדק ונמצא כשר
באישור הרבנות הראשית לישראל

Surprisingly, the above Hebrew words are just two plain lines of text.  They're not part of any logo, emblem, or symbol.

Kashrus agencies commonly use logos, emblems, and/or symbols as certification marks.  They tend to register these logos as trademarks, to help prevent their unauthorized use.  [(Source.)](https://oukosher.org/blog/industrial-kosher/the-unauthorized-kosher-symbol/)

## My question

Considering the lack of any kosher logo, emblem, or symbol:  Is it still safe to assume that this roasted buckwheat really is kosher according to the Chief Rabbinate of Israel?

## Photo

A partial photo of the package is below.  I've drawn a blue arrow pointing to the kashrus claim.

[image: Partial photo of package]

You may also view [the full package](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GW0yO.jpg), if you wish.

## Edit

I made some inquiries.  Please see [my comment below](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/139422/a-foods-rabbanut-kashrus-claim-is-in-plain-text-theres-no-kosher-symbol-logo#comment466034_139422).

Comment: This seems like asking for a practical ruling.

Comment: The Hebrew text is quite common for products sold in Israel, they don't always have other kashrut symbols. The best approach is to ask once someone in the know (can be a local rabbi where you purchased the product or the manufacturer) about the supervising agency. Once you know it is being supervised, then you can trust future packages. Otherwise, especially with products manufactured in China, you're trusting the manufacturer which might have copied packaging from somewhere else. If you buy it in Israel, the supermarket will most often have kashrut supervision which makes it easier

Comment: @mbloch:  I contacted Zakuson, which is the Canadian importer.  They emailed me a copy of the certification letter for all kasha made by Qingdao Cereals & Noodles Industries Co. Ltd,, though the importer's name wasn't mentioned on the letter.  The certification is by Badatz Beit Yossef, and expires in April '24.  I phoned my local kashrus agency (COR), which said that Badatz Beit Yosef is an acceptable certification for Chinese kasha.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would ask the manufacturer about which local Rabbanut actually certifies the product on behalf of the Rabbanut Ha'reishit.  I would also contact Rabbanut about this product.
https://www.gov.il/he/departments/topics/national_kosher/govil-landing-page

Someone who works in the Rabbanut told me: According to Israeli law, all imported products must be certified by the Rabbanut, unless they have an official exception. That is why imported products such as ones bearing a OU hechsher will also say באישור הרבנות הראשית לישראל as this is required legally. It could be that it bears another hechsher but was inadvertently not put on. Or it could be that it was just replicated from another product.

Comment: I made some inquiries.  Please see [my comment above](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/139422/a-foods-rabbanut-kashrus-claim-is-in-plain-text-theres-no-kosher-symbol-logo#comment466034_139422).